# akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]]

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

```
[error] akka.ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to 
[akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded 
[akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to 
[akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did 
not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]]
```

I have tried including logger start up timeout value as well and it seems not working and same issue is getting reflected.

```
        akka {
          loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
          loglevel = "INFO"
          logger-startup-timeout = 30s
          http {
            host-connection-pool {
              max-connections = 16
              max-open-requests = 128
            }
        
            server {
              parsing.max-header-value-length = 512k
            }
          }
        }
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to set the `logging-filter` parameter:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

If this does not solve your issue, please (re)read carefully [the official documentation on how to perform Classic Logging](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html) as you might have some dependency issue.